# How Do I Force Redrawing (drawRect) of a SubView When it Changes Dimensions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uikit

I have a UIView that contains a row of subclasses of `UIView`. The subclass has overridden `drawRect`: and has set  `contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw`.

As the user squashes and stretches the parent container the `child views` squash and stretch. As the shape change occurs I would like to have `drawRect` called repeatedly to change the contents of the `child views`. So far I have been unsuccessful. What is the correct way to do this?

Cheers,

Doug

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In Cocoa, you rarely (if ever) call drawRect - you just mark the region or view as needing update, and it will be scheduled for redrawing. This allows redraws for multiple invalidations to be collapsed together.

For Cocoa Touch, you want either [[view setNeedsDisplay]](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay?language=objc), or [setNeedsDisplayinRect:(CGRect)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622587-setneedsdisplayinrect?language=objc)

Comment: I tried doing exactly that. No effect. Nuthin.

In the subclass I overrode the setTransform: method thusly:

- (void)setTransform:(CGAffineTransform)newValue {

   [super setTransform:newValue];

   [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

Comment: Apparently, I bit of code futzing now has setNeedsDisplay firing properly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call [view setNeedsLayout], this should cause the subviews to receive a drawRect: call if the layout changes. I haven't tested this, however.

Comment: Some say `setNeedsDisplay`, some say `setNeedsLayout`.. What are the different implications here?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little crazy, but it makes logical sense, and has a great visual result.  I'm working with a `NSLayoutManager` and a couple `NSTextContainer`s, laying out text in two columns.  Because I'm using multiple text containers (and I'm not sure I want multiple `UITextView`), I'm overriding the `draw(rect: CGRect)` method of `MyDrawingView: UIView`.

The problem is that using `self.contentMode = .redraw` still results in some minor stretching on rotation--significant enough to be a deal-breaker.

I noticed that setting `contentMode = .left`, or even `contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` was close to what I wanted, in terms of pixel-perfect rotation.  But obviously, I wasn't getting the draw call I needed.

So--I overrode `layoutSubviews()`, switched the `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFit`, called `super.layoutSubviews()`, and then switched it back.  :P

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentMode = .redraw
}
```

It is...perfect.