# when re-render layout of UIView, the draw function is not triggered

Tags: ios, uiview, ios10

I am using Xcode 8.1

I subclass UIView:

```
class DrawingView: UIView {
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        print("drawing...")
   }

   override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      // re-renader the layout when finger moves
      setNeedsLayout()
      super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
   }
}
```

When I run my app, the `draw(...)` function above get called **once** when app was launching. (I saw the print message)

Then, I finger move on the screen, I expected that `draw(...)` should get called for every finger movement (since I called `setNeedsLayout()`),
but the `draw(...)` function never get called. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Force Redrawing (drawRect) of a SubView When it Changes Dimensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441760/how-do-i-force-redrawing-drawrect-of-a-subview-when-it-changes-dimensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger the view to re-draw, call `setNeedsDisplay()`, instead of `setNeedsLayout()`

Comment: Calling `setNeedsLayout()` will cause `layoutSubviews()` to be called. The implementation of `layoutSubviews()` should set the frames of all the subviews. Although you can set frames of views anywhere, it is recommended that you do it in that method, for both performance and code-readability. When you are using constraints, you do not need to implement this methods, the frames are set by the auto layout-system for you using the constraints.